# Why `features = ["std"]` is not necessary in the `[dev-dependencies]` some crates like `sp-io`?

Tags: rust, no-std

We often use some basic substrate crates such as `sp-core`, and `sp-io` while doing pallet tests. In general, those dependencies are put under `[dev-dependencies]`. But I have an issue with whether we should add `default-features = false` or not. Seems both work.

For example:

```
# pallet crate level

[dependencies]
frame-system = = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.37" }
# no sp-io here

[dev-dependencies]
# With`default-features = false`
sp-io = = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.37" }

or

# Without default-features = false
sp-io = = { git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.37" }
```

In the pallet tests (both ways can compile):

```rs
// mock.rs
use sp_io::TestExternalities;
```

Check from the substrate repo:

```rs
/// Type alias for Externalities implementation used in tests.
#[cfg(feature = "std")]  // this line
pub type TestExternalities = sp_state_machine::TestExternalities<sp_core::Blake2Hasher>;
```

As the code snippet shows, the `TestExternalities` is only available under`std` feature.So **why** the first way, `With default-features = false` can be compiled?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the `frame-system` also depends on `sp-io`. And you enable the `std` for the `frame-system` in the test env, which also enables the `sp-io/std` for the whole scope.